# IIF Functions in Access 2013

Tags: ms-access

I am Using MS Access 2013 to create queries at work. I am having issues finding examples writing Iif Functions for the query so let me lay my thought process out.

IF[Table1]=2 and IF[Table2] contains("string") then return that whole row, Else cut the whole row and never show me again.

Basically I have a query where I want all EVENT_TYPE that = 2 to only return the first and last row and cut all the other rows that contain #2 in the middle. Here is a sample of the Query.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eXlJ.png

Comment: IIF functions if I understand correctly what you need is not what you need. Check the where statment in sql WHERE EVENT_TYPE = 2 AND .... study some sql ; ) or try to use the access interface...   never show me again DELETE from ....

Comment: The Where Clause wouldn't help here that is essentially just the criteria spot in Access. I can already filter to where I either see no type 2's or all of them. The problem is I want to see the first and last one for any given driver on any given day plus all the other even types.